# Python, Crear lista extrayendo los datos de un array bidimensional

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un Reto de Python. El ejercicio trata de mostrar una lista con los datos que contiene un array bidimensional. La cuestión es que con una comprehension list consigo mostrarla en un print. Pero intento obtener el mismo resultado con bucles for anidados y no lo consigo, me cuesta un poco entenderlos.

Con la lista comprehension: (La salida es la esperada), pero con for anidados no consigo hacerlo, ni entenderlo.

```
4 -> Flatten the following list to a new list
output -> [["FINLAND","FIN","HELSINKI"],["SWEDEN","SWE","STOCKHOLM"],["NORMWAY","NOR","OSLO"]]

countries = [[("Finland", "Helsinki")], [
    ("Sweden", "Stockholm")], [("Normway", "Oslo")]]

new_list = [country for row in countries for column in row for country in column]
print(new_list)

countries = [[("Finland", "Helsinki")],
             [("Sweden", "Stockholm")],
             [("Normway", "Oslo")]]


for row in countries:
    new_list2 = []
    for column in row:
        for country in column:
            count = 0
            new_list2.append(country)
            count += 1


print(country)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Para convertir una comprensión de listas a ciclos `for` únicamente tienes que ir leyendo de izquierda a derecha e ir declarando los `for` tal como los encuentras.

En este caso primero tienes el `for row in countries`, luego `for column in row` y por último `for country in column`, los declaras tal cual como los encuentras.

```
countries = [[("Finland", "Helsinki")], [("Sweden", "Stockholm")], [("Normway", "Oslo")]]

new_list = [country for row in countries for column in row for country in column]
print('Con comprensión de listas:')
print(new_list)

new_list2 = []

for row in countries:
    for column in row:
        for country in column:
            new_list2.append(country)

print('Con ciclos for anidados:')
print(new_list2)
```

Esto imprime:

```
Con comprensión de listas:
['Finland', 'Helsinki', 'Sweden', 'Stockholm', 'Normway', 'Oslo']
Con ciclos for anidados:
['Finland', 'Helsinki', 'Sweden', 'Stockholm', 'Normway', 'Oslo']
```

Que es el mismo resultado que tenías en tu comprensión de listas.

Answer (score 0):

```
countries = [["FINLAND","FIN","HELSINKI"],["SWEDEN","SWE","STOCKHOLM"],["NORMWAY","NOR","OSLO"]]

sal = []

for row in countries:
    new_list2 = []
    count = 0
    for country in row:
        if( count != 1 ):
            new_list2.append(country)
        count += 1
    sal.append( new_list2 )
    
print( sal )
```

devuelve:

```
[['FINLAND', 'HELSINKI'], ['SWEDEN', 'STOCKHOLM'], ['NORMWAY', 'OSLO']]
```

Explicación:

- Primero creamos una lista donde cargar el resultado.
- Dentro del primer `for`, creamos una lista auxiliar. el iniciamos el contador que nos permitirá eliminar el segundo `item` de la lista.
- En el if, evaluamos si el contador es uno, en cuyo caso, salimos e incrementamos el contador, de no serlo, cargamos en la lista `aux`, el valor que tenemos.
- Cada vez que salimos del `for` interior, cargamos la lista `aux`, el la de salida.

Comment: Una breve explicación no vendría mal :-)...

Comment: Hola Maestro, estaba en eso, me agarro con las manos en la masa.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev, lo malo de las ediciones, es que parece que yo hubiese hecho todo bien.

Comment: El OP pide un resultado que sea una lista de strings; el código que muestras da una lista de listas.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, HeytalePazguato es lo que buscaba, y despues de dar mil vueltas he visto que el fallo era donde habia declarado la lista inicialmente (dentro del primer for) en vez de fuera, creía que no influia. Muchas gracias a todos Cris223511.dev, Marce Puente, Candid Moe y HeytalePazquato